# Fatal error: Call to a member function persist() on a non-object

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, composer-php

`Fatal error: Call to a member function persist() on a non-object`

I am using composer,mongodb doctrine,php

```
namespace Documents;

public $document_id;
public $id;
public $model;
public function __construct($model){
     $this->model = $model;
     $car = new Car('Ford');
     dm->persist($car);
     dm->flush();
     var_dump($car->__toString());
```

Comment: Please paste here a piece of code where it occurs. it's a simple issue - the variable which calls `persist` method is not a proper object, but a NULL.

Comment: You should have cut your comment short on "not a proper object", as the non-object is everything but an object. Not necessarily a NULL.

Comment: @PiotrPasich i am trying to execute example code of mongodbdoctrine .My persis and flush functions are giving this kind of error .

Comment: I do not see the place where you define `$dm` variable

Comment: can u plss write a small demo code here it ould be helpful for me understand

Comment: @PiotrPasich how do i define $dm variable

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got defined `$dm` variable in your example. Please try:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$dm->persist($car);
$dm->flush();
```

It's well described in a documentation - http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html